# Maximum-density multiple-choice knapsack problem

Tags: optimization, np-hard, knapsack-problems

I am looking for work done on solving a problem (specifically I'm looking for an approximation algorithm) which is very similar to a combination of two variations of the knapsack problem: [maximum-density knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems) and [multiple-choice knapsack problem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-24777-7_11).

The problem is:

We have $t$ sets $S_1,...,S_t$ of elements, where each set is of size $k$: $S_i=\{e_{i,1},e_{i,2},...,e_{i,k}\}$.
for each element $e_{i,j}$ there is a profit $p_{i,j}$ and a cost $c_{i,j}$.
It holds that $$c_{i_1,j}=c_{i_2,j},i_1 \neq i_2$$(the cost is the same for each set it only depends on the element's index in the set) so let us denote $c_{j}$ from now on.
Both the Profit and the Cost are monotonically increasing: $$c_{j_1} \leq c_{j_2} \text{ if } {j_1} \leq {j_2}$$ $$p_{i, j_1} \leq p_{i, j_2} \text{ if } {j_1} \leq {j_2}$$
The problem is to choose one element from each set to construct a set of $t$ elemets ${e_{1,j_1},e_{2,j_2},...,e_{t,j_t}}$ with profits ${p_{1,j_1},p_{2,j_2},...,p_{t,j_t}}$ and costs ${c_{j_1},c_{j_2},...,c_{j_t}}$
such that the following exprssion is maximized:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t}p_{i,j_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{t}c_{j_i}} = \frac{p_{1,j_1}+p_{2,j_2}+...+p_{t,j_t}}{{c_{j_1}+c_{j_2}+...+c_{j_t}}}$$
and the following expression holds for some constant $0 \leq r \leq 1$:
$$ {\sum_{i=1}^{t}p_{i,j_i}} \geq r*{\sum_{i=1}^{t}p_{i,k}}$$

Intuitively, you need to maximize the ratio between the profit and the cost while having at least some portion of the profit.

As I said this problem can probably be reduced to a combination of maximum-density knapsack problem and multiple-choice knapsack problem, so any information on that (and not specifically on the problem I stated) can be helpful as well.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about your situation?  I see a specification of a problem and some statements, but I don't see a concrete question.  We're a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific answerable question about your situation.  Do you want to know whether it is in NP?  whether it is NP-complete?  for an approximation algorithm?  something else?

Comment: I want an approximation algorithm, sorry if that wasn't clear